# Measure flipped image

Tags: geometry

Image B is a mirrored version of Image A. Image C is the two images put together.

How can I calculate the difference that generated the dark blue area in Image C?

[image: Image A]
[image: Image B]
[image: Image C]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only need to consider the part(s) of your region(s) that extend over your axis of reflection -- and only on the side that extends over less than the other.  If the region(s) lie only in one half, there is no overlap.

Also, your overlap region will be symmetric with respect to your axis of reflection.

The maximum distance of your region(s) from the axis of symmetry (let's call this $x=0$) will be the leftmost filled-in pixel on the left side, and the rightmost filled-in pixel on the right side.

The maximum distance on the right side is the lesser; let's say the blue rectangle extends to $x=d$ on the right side.  (It extends to $x=-D$ on the left size, with $D$ positive and $D>d$.)

Now we look at all the pixels $(x,y)$ between $x=0$ and $x=d$ and check for each pixel if $(-x, y)$ is part of a region.  If so, then this is part of the overlap.

Once this is all done, then we reflect the overlapped region from $x=0$ to $x=d$ across the axis to create its mirror image from $x=0$ to $x=-d$, and we're done.